# for loop accepts one extra value than the loop condition

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, scanf

I have written a program which accepts a value from a user and then iterates over that value in a for loop. in for loop I accept numbers to be stored in the array. 
My problem is for loop accepts one extra value than specified by user.

```
int main()
{
  int  i = 0;
  int  a;
  int no_of_boxcars = 0;
  double array[10];
  double boxcart_wt = 0;
  //printf("Enter the no of wagons");
  scanf_s("%d", &no_of_boxcars);        // no of boxcars
  for (i = 0; i<=no_of_boxcars;++i)
  {
    printf("%d \t", i);
    scanf_s("%lf ", &boxcart_wt);   //weight in boxcar

    array[i] = boxcart_wt;
  }
}
```

if the user enters 3 it should accept 3 values if

```
for (i = 0; i<no_of_boxcars;++i)
{
  //but here accepts 4 values
}
```

if the user enters 3 it should accept 4 values if

```
for (i = 0; i<=no_of_boxcars;++i)
{
  //and here accepts 5 values
}
```

Comment: "*one extra value*": `<`  is not the same as `<=`.

Comment: For `no_of_boxcars` being equal to `3`, this loop `for (i = 0; i < no_of_boxcars; ++i) { ...}` iterates exactly three time.

Comment: @xing, thankyou you are right this was the problem. i works now

Comment: @alk, yes you are right they are not the same, but my question was my loop was accepting one extra value than expected. So if i remove  trailing space from the "%lf " then its working perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A space in the `scanf` format matches *any* white-space, and any number of consecutive white-space.

The problem with a trailing space is that then `scanf` must continue reading until it reads something that *isn't* a white-space, otherwise it doesn't know when the spaces ends.

That leads to the problem that you need to give some extra non white-space input.

For all but two formats (`"%c"` and `"%["`) the `scanf` function automatically reads and discards leading white-space. So it's usually not needed to include spaces in a format string. Except perhaps for those two formats that doesn't skip white-space.

Read e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes in C go from `0..n-1`. In your for loop you go from `0..n` and that is one too many. Change

```
for (i = 0; i<=no_of_boxcars;++i)
```

to

```
for (i = 0; i<no_of_boxcars;++i)
```

Comment: the problem is not with the for loop it is when I am accepting the value inside for loop, it has a "%lf " space after %lf. so after removing this space, it worked fine

Comment: @AmeyaPatil, your problem was in the loop test also, and the question is entitled as such... don't say now that the problem is not the addressed in this answer.  The error signalled in this answer **is also an error.**  It's a pity that you refuse the answer of Paul... as you stated that clearly that your program was asking for one extra value.

Comment: @LuisColorado , I accept my mistake, but the cases given clearly states what the problem was.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, your answer addressed the question in one sense, but the problem was one step ahead of this. I respect your answer too.